# Symfony Define the database for authentication

Tags: database, symfony, authentication

I work on a project with Symfony2 and for now i can authenticate on my website.

But my problem is now when a user want to authenticate, i want to use a another database for some reasons. 
So how can i say to symfony to use for example the db2 for authenticate and the db1 for the website?

If anyone can help me, thanks!

EDIT:

Thank's for your answer, i write this:

```
    orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            mappings:
                ContactBundle:  ~
        users:
            connection: general
            mappings:
                UsersBundle: ~
```

But i've this error:

> The class 'SymagContact\Bundle\UsersBundle\Entity\Users' was not found in the chain configured namespaces SymagContact\Bundle\SymagContactBundle\Entity

Comment: So am I correct in assuming that your Contact entity is related to the User entity?

Comment: What did you mean by "related"?

Comment: Do you have a Doctrine 2 mapping between the two entities?  Is there maybe a One to Many relation between User and Contacts?  Are there any entities in your contact bundle with an association with the user entity?  The error message seems to indicate that there is.

Comment: My Users entity didn't have association with any entities in contact bundle...

Comment: And vice versa?  None of your contact entities associate with your user bundle entity?  Hate to keep asking but the error message indicates there is.

Comment: No my users entity haven't association with other entity.

Comment: Interesting.  I assume you have cleared the cache and that you are not mixing annotations with yaml or xml.  Is your code on github?  I can take a look.

Comment: Thanks but your github code does not match your question (no Symag stuff). So consider updating your question with actual code and error messages.  Better yet, check in your app directory as well as your composer.json file.  You have a simple configuration issue somewhere.

Comment: I've update the error message.

Comment: This will probably be my last comment here.  You really need to ponder the relation between your posted question and your actual code.  And you need to think about what information someone who is trying to help needs.  Especially if the potential helper has explicitly asked you for something.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can have more than one EntityManager:

You have to setup your DBAL connections like this:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   "%database_driver%"
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8

            db2:
                driver:   "%db2_database_driver%"
                host:     "%db2_database_host%"
                port:     "%db2_database_port%"
                dbname:   "%db2_database_name%"
                user:     "%db2_database_user%"
                password: "%db2_database_password%"
```

Then in the ORM section you can map your UserBundle namespace to the db2 connection:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    AppBundle:  ~
                    AcmeStoreBundle: ~
            customer:
                connection: db
                mappings:
                    AcmeUserBundle: ~
```

The rest is just the same: Have a UserProvider registered that follows the UserProviderInterface.

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html for more information.